# Change a function that returns reference to return a mutable reference?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a binary search tree to try and learn about how memory is managed etc. At the moment, I have a function `find_nearest` which queries the tree for the subtree containing the specified value, or the one closest to it if it does not contain that value. My code looks like this:

```
struct Tree<T> {
    data: T,
    children: [Option<Box<Tree<T>>>; 2],
}

impl<T: Ord + Copy> Tree<T> {
    pub fn find_nearest(&self, data: &T) -> &Tree<T> {
        if *data == self.data {
            self
        } else {
            match &self.children[(*data > self.data) as usize] {
                None => self,
                Some(n) => n.find_nearest(data),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a function to add a value to the tree after it has already been constructed, so I figured I could reuse `find_nearest` and simply change one of the returned Tree's children, but I cannot because `find_nearest` returns and immutable reference and I need a mutable reference to mutate hte `Tree`'s children.

So, I figured I could reuse `find_nearest` and write a slightly different variant called `find_nearest_mut` that takes a `&mut self` and returns a `&mut Tree<T>`, and this seemed to line up with some methods I had seen in the standard libary for `Vec` and `LinkedList`.

In all my attempts so far, the issue seems to be in the `match` statement. It says that the match itself is a borrow, and then the `None` and `Some(n)` statements are either secondary mutable borrows or moves depending if I tack on a `&mut` or not.

I've run into issues like this before where I was getting myself into a corner by using the wrong syntax, and if I had used the correct syntax it would have removed some of the intermediary borrows/moves, so I figure there is some issue with how I am using `match` or something, but I do not know the language well enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually valid, and the fact that the borrow checker does not accept it is a known shortcoming in the current borrow checker. It will be fixed with the next-gen Polonius borrow checker (try running your code with `cargo +nightly rustc -- -Z polonius`).

Until then, the fix is to repeat the calculation:

```rust
impl<T: Ord + Copy> Tree<T> {
    pub fn find_nearest_mut(&mut self, data: &T) -> &mut Tree<T> {
        if *data == self.data {
            self
        } else {
            match &mut self.children[(*data > self.data) as usize] {
                None => self,
                Some(_) => self.children[(*data > self.data) as usize]
                    .as_mut()
                    .unwrap()
                    .find_nearest_mut(data),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is still informative to me because now I know of the `Some(_)` syntax I can use to not move out of the `Some`. Doing the calculation twice is kinda stinky and it would be nicer to be able to use `n`, but having to do something like this to make the borrow checker happy is OK by me!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is to first check if the child is `None` by immutable borrowing to return self. If it is not, then borrow it mutably to return the nearest of the child.

```rust
pub fn find_nearest_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, data: &T) -> &'a mut Tree<T> {
        if *data == self.data {
            self
        } else {
            if let None = self.children[(*data > self.data) as usize] {
                self
            } else {
                self.children[(*data > self.data) as usize]
                    .as_mut()
                    .unwrap()
                    .find_nearest_mut(data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This fails because of [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21906) and should be valid.

As this code is valid and should be accepted by the borrow checker, we could use some unsafe code to trick the borrow checker into accepting it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=473e6e2981c67081a7d65dfae208b298))

```rust
struct Tree<T> {
    data: T,
    children: [Option<Box<Tree<T>>>; 2],
}

impl<T: Ord + Copy> Tree<T> {
    pub fn find_nearest_mut(&mut self, data: &T) -> &mut Tree<T> {
        if *data == self.data {
            self
        } else {
            match &mut self.children[(*data > self.data) as usize] {
                None => self,
                Some(n) => unsafe {&mut *(&mut **n as *mut Tree<T>)}.find_nearest_mut(data),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows the borrow `&mut self.children[(*data > self.data) as usize]` to be really short by converting its lifetime into a longer lifetime.